# why response eror listener is but response listener is in the json array request?

Tags: java, arraylist, android-recyclerview, android-volley

my app it has to take data from server
and put it in the array list with recycler view
Listener dosent working and when i run the app and it just open  Response.ErrorListener
i cant find what is wrong with tHAT
AND I HAVE TRIED IN SO MANY DEVICES

```
private void gitems()
{
    String url="http://novindevelopers.ir/jsonarrayrequest.json";
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("در حال دریافت اطلاعات");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.show();

    Response.Listener<JSONArray>  arrayListener = new Response.Listener<JSONArray>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response)
        {
            try {
                //JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                for (int j = 0; j < response.length(); j++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(j);
                    String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
                    String email = jsonObject.getString("email");
                    String phone = jsonObject.getString("phone");
                    items.add(new modellitems(name,email,phone));
                }
            }catch (JSONException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            adaptorr.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

    Response.ErrorListener errorListener = new Response.ErrorListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "this", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    };

    JsonArrayRequest arrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET ,url , null , arrayListener,errorListener );
    MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(arrayRequest);
}
```

Comment: _"it just open Response.ErrorListener i cant find what is wrong"_ because you're ignoring the error. Instead of just showing Toast message can you please log the error like `Log.e("ERROR : ", error.getMessage());` and [edit] the question, post stack trace here?

Comment: Response.ErrorListener is "open" because there is an error in your request,you need to see what that error is in order to solve it,as suggested `Log.d("Error":error.toString());` in your code under the Toast line in `ErrorListener`,then run it again,Look for the log in the console under "run" and see what error is given.